# How can I change the ubercart order templates?

Tags: 6, theming, ubercart

I have been searching around trying to find the answer to my issue, on and off for months. I'm using Drupal 6, [Ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart) and [Ubercart Marketplace](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart_marketplace). I'm trying to add the sellers address onto the packing slip as the Returns address. Could really do without receiving products at my address.

I'm fairly confident of how I'll pull that info in. Something like:

```
<?php $seller = arg(1);
    $account = user_load($seller);
    $seller_id = $account->uid;

    $var = content_profile_load('profile', $seller_id);

    print $var->field_location[0]['street'];
     ............. and so on... 

                    ?>
```

So I've read: [Changing invoice templates for Ubercart 2.3 and later](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/developer/17385/changing_invoice_templates_ubercart_23_and_later).

So I copied the `.tpl.php` files from `modules/ubercart/uc_order/templates` over to my theme and flushed the caches.

However any changes (even just adding some text) aren't being displayed. I then just tried editing the original `modules/ubercart/uc_order/templates/packingslip.tpl.php` ... Still no changes are being shown... I keep relentlessly flushing the caches in hope...

Soul searching on Google just keeps bringing up the method described in the link above...

What am I missing?

EDIT:

It is because i'm using module called [Ubercart Invoice](https://drupal.org/sandbox/fuerst/1249740)... This module adds VAT information to orders and invoices, useful for European countries. It does so by overriding the normal templates with this file: /sites/all/modules/ubercart_invoice/templates/uc_order-invoice-number.tpl.php

Tbh, I'm not 100% on how it does what it does but I do know that if I edit that file, the changes are picked up...